# Docker external host mapping

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have a container running on a docker-host, the docker-host has a host entry like:

```
externalServiceHostEntry <external_service_IP>
```

I want the service inside my container to be able to talk to the externalService, and I want that service to use an alias hostname (because the container may be deployed in different docker-hosts with different host entries). As such i'd like to do something like this when I run the container:

```
docker run --add-host <alias>:<external_service_IP> ...
```

However, I can't do this as the external_service_IP may be changed by our infrastructure team at any point, and they only want to maintain the docker-host's etc/hosts file. So i want to do something like:

```
docker run --add-host <alias>:externalServiceHostEntry ...
```

Though i know this won't work for the obvious reason that the docker-host's externalServiceHostEntry hostname will have no meaning in the container /etc/hosts.

How can I achieve a setup, so that our infrastructure team can change the docker-hosts' etc/hosts file at will, and yet the service running in my container will still be able to communicate with the external service via a constant alias?

Comment: Can you mount the host file from the host into the container?

Comment: @ssc327 Probably, but is that a very docker-esque approach?

Comment: That's what I would do but let's see if there are alternatives...